# Msado60_Backcompat crashes in CCommand::CreateParameter

Tags: ado

I am developing an ADO application (32 bit) on Windows 7 64 bit SP1 (all updates installed): The app must run on Win XP. According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589/en-us I am using msado60_backcompat. That worked well until lately, but now it crashes.

My code (snippets):

```
_CommandPtr cmd(__uuidof(Command));
cmd->ActiveConnection = dbconn;
cmd->CommandText = _T("SELECT [si] FROM [TTable] WHERE [TTable].[ti1]=?");
cmd->Parameters->Append(cmd->CreateParameter(L"@ti1", adTinyInt, adParamInput, 1, 7));
```

CreateParameter is implemented in msado60_backcompat:

```
inline _ParameterPtr Command15::CreateParameter ( _bstr_t Name, enum DataTypeEnum Type, enum ParameterDirectionEnum Direction, ADO_LONGPTR Size, const _variant_t & Value )
{
  struct _Parameter * _result = 0;
  HRESULT _hr = raw_CreateParameter(Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value, &_result);
  if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
  return _ParameterPtr(_result, false);
}
```

raw_CreateParameter() calls into msado15.dll into CCommand::CreateParameter. There a crash occurs at offset 0x34f (offset inside the function):

> First-chance exception at 0x655ed5a6 (msado15.dll) in adosqlbugcheck.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x655ed5a6 (msado15.dll) in adosqlbugcheck.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.

Msado60_Backcompat.tlb: 73728 bytes, 29.4.2011
msado15.dll: 6.1.7601.17514, 1019904 bytes, 21.11.2010

The error does not occur if I use msado15.dll.

Can someone reproduce the error? Is there a solution?

Comment: There isn't an SP3 for "SQL Server 2008 R2"... SP1 unless you mean "SQL Server 2008"

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1. And also (coming with MSVC 2011?) SQL Server 2008. The Service Pack 3 indeed is for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter wrote a short comment why he downvoted my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is solved. I was #import-ing the msado60_backcompat.tlb from "C:\Program Files\Common Files". If I import the version from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files" it works. The compiler generates tlh files from both tlb files with exactly the same UUIDs and everything else, they only differ in that the one contains

```
typedef __int64 ADO_LONGPTR; 
typedef ADO_LONGPTR PositionEnum_Param;
```

While the other contains

```
typedef long ADO_LONGPTR; 
typedef enum PositionEnum PositionEnum_Param;
```

From my understanding of COM interfaces this should not happen. But since MS commits they really made a mistake it seems to just be the way it is.

Just for information, MS has a new solution coming up: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft's new solution simply fixes the UUID issue, but would still cause your issue. The tlb files in Program Files (x86) will typedef ADO_LONGPTR as long, but the x64 versions will typedef as an __int64. Unfortunately, using 'Program Files (x86)' would fail on non-x64 machines.

Comment: Going to second @adzm on this one, the `#import "C:\Program Files\...` issue remains. I got bitten by this, ended up putting `msado60_Backcompat_i386.tlb` in the project folder and doing `#import "msado60_Backcompat_i386.tlb"` and all seems to be fine.

Comment: That crazy microsoft and their breakages. I am directly importing msado60_Backcompat_i386.tlb as suggested by ta.speot.is and this addresses the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Finally! For the record, this problem also impacts e.g. the ADO Find method. I solved it by taking the generated `msado28.tlh` and .tli files from an `#import "msado28.tlb"`, placed them into my project, and modified the tlh by surrounding the offending typedef with preprocessor directives, as in: `#ifdef WIN64 typedef __int64 ADO_LONGPTR; #else typedef long ADO_LONGPTR #endif`.